# Adding new activity to Decompiled APK

Tags: android, android-activity, apk, decompiling

I know a little about the dextool and apktool which can be used to decompile the apk. but neither of them explicitly explain adding any new activity to the decompiled APK. is it possible, and if its can you give me an example or any link directs me to explanation? thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you decompile, edit in eclipse and recompile an apk? Step by Step?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184419/how-do-you-decompile-edit-in-eclipse-and-recompile-an-apk-step-by-step)

Comment: -1 I'm not going to answer your question because I suspect that you want to create something bad with it...

Comment: actually no, I wont do anything bad with it... and I think this is not the same issue we are talking about, he just want to change the screen resolution, manifest file or a layout xml. What I want is adding new activity, I know how to change values, resources, or adding some toast messages to the apk but dont know adding new activity... thanks for your quick response

Comment: also I don't understand why you gave -1 rep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly do not use this in a sinister way, we've got enough people doing that already. The decompiled app can be added to eclipse by importing from existing source. Within this you can add a new class and then export a signed package (signing it with a new key).

Step by step can be found [here](http://kkinder.com/2011/11/27/so-you-want-to-reverse-engineer-an-android-app-apk/).

Comment: decompiled app has only smali files is it normal or Im doing something wrong? and thanks for your answer, I'm not that kind of person.